# $_FILES in CodeIgniter's model class

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am working with codeigniter and have created a model class for working with file uploads, manipulations, and CRUD for records relating to files. Everything is working as expected however I am faced with an obsessive compulsive issue where it does not feel right to me to be calling the $_FILES superglobal from within the model class. I had thought about creating a variable within the controller and assigning the contents of $_FILES to it and then passing it to the model for processing, but this seemed like a wasted step.

Another scenario I was thinking about was creating a separate library for the upload functions I have created, but I'm not sure if that would make sense either. I feel like I should be obtaining the values from the $_FILES array and sending them somewhere for processing...am I putting too much thought into this? How have you handled this situation in past cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extended the file helper and added a function which analyzes the $_FILES array and returns an array of the information needed. I then am able to call this function from my controller and pass it's value into the model that is doing the custom business logic. This allows for the model to remain abstract, which simplifies unit testing of the model.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call $_Files from the controller . I think you are calling it from model so it not working properly there because after upload data goes in controller.

And the second idea on which you are thinking to take the value in variable in controller and then pass it into model so it will work surely but so have to define variable properly like it should be multidimensional array.
First of all print_r($_Files) and then check the value in controller. 
I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I am currently calling $_FILES within the model and everything is working. However, I am attempting to follow the rule where one's model class should be "plug and play" for unit testing purposes and to follow a strict design pattern. From what I'm seeing the best way to do this might be to pass the $_FILES array into the model as suggested.